# How to properly return a value from a PropertyMethod?

Tags: c#, ado.net

First of all, sorry (AGAIN) for my bad english.

Hello. I am still pretty new to C#.NET and we are now tasked by our professor to make a simple banking system using an ADO.NET database. My only problem now is that I can't seem to return the values from the `PropertyMethod` I created.

Here's how it works: I log in using my auto-generated username and password, in which in the next window, I would be able to deposit or withdraw. I wanted to display in my text boxes the retrieved information from the database.

Is there a proper way to return a value from the `PropertyMethod`? Or could I just employ other ways to properly retrieve the values I want? Thanks for all your answers.

Here is  a part of my class library which authenticates login inputs and should return the values I want:

EDIT: I tried to look at the debugger to trace what's happening to the values, but they are returning nulls.

EDIT 2: Removed unnecessary codes.

EDIT 3: Thanks for noticing my errors. I have already fixed them. My program is working fine now.

here is the propery method

```
#region pm
public string FinalName
{
 get { return finalName; }
 set { finalName = value; }
}

    public string FinalUname
    {
        get { return finalUname; }
        set { finalUname = value; }
    }

    public string Acnum
    {
        get { return acnum; }
        set { acnum = value; }
    }

    public string Pass
    {
        get { return pass; }
        set { pass = value; }
    }

    public string Actype
    {
        get { return actype; }
        set { actype = value; }
    }

    public string Mname
    {
        get { return mname; }
        set { mname = value; }
    }

    public string Lname
    {
        get { return lname; }
        set { lname = value; }
    }

    public string Fname
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value; }
    }
    decimal bal;

    public decimal Bal
    {
        get { return bal; }
        set { bal = value; }
    }


    public bool Dup
    {
        get { return dup; }
        set { dup = value; }
    }
    #endregion
```

and here is the code for authenticating login.

```
    public bool authenticateData(string uname, string pass)
    {
        bool found = false;
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand readData = new SqlCommand("AuthenticateLogin", mySqlConnection);
        readData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        readData.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = uname;
        readData.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pass;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = readData.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            found = true;

            Actype = dr.GetString(3);
            Bal = dr.GetDecimal(5);
            Acnum = dr.GetString(6);
            FinalName = dr.GetString(0) + " " + dr.GetString(2) + " " + dr.GetString(1);
            break;
        }

        mySqlConnection.Close();
        return found;
    }
}
}
```

And here is my windows form:

```
    private void Transact_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here is where my bug occurs

        txtName.Text = da.finalName;
        txtUsername.Text = da.finalUname;
        txtActType.Text = da.actype;
        txtBal.Text = da.Bal.ToString();

        type = txtActType.Text;

    }
```

Comment: Please post only relevant code, and while posting long codes specify the line no where you are having problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your windows form you're accessing properties of an object called `da` ... but what is that? Are you actually setting `da` to a class of results anywhere? Your example code doesn't show this anywhere.

In `authenticateData` you use a datareader to populate some properties with your results, but those properties belong to what - the class that contains the `authenticateData` method? What is da, and how are you expecting it to have the values of your results?